# specific interface name for an interface in linux

Tags: linux, driver, device-driver

Is there a possibility that I can hardcode interface name(say eth1) to a specific interface in the linux driver code?

This is in a controlled environemnt only, so breaking from default linux way(dynamically assigning name) is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to do that; you could instead just fiddle with the dynamic assignment mechanism. `udev` has configuration files that control how names are assigned to devices, and if I remember it  will also allow you to create links with handy names for given device names... so you can probably achieve your effect by re-configuring rather than re-coding.

Check out the man page and docs for `udev`.

Comment: Are you not *consciously* using udev, or is your system really not using udev? i.e. do you have an "old" or custom "slim" Linux distro? If there's no udev in the system then I don't have any other advice, as I don't know my way around the code.

Comment: its a custom made embedded linux system.I got the way...
Just I need to do 
{
                strcpy(dev->name,"eth1");

}

Answer (score 0):

You can rename network devices which are not up using the "ifconfig" command or the ioctl it uses. I strongly recommend that you don't :)